# /dev/mapper/fedora-root is full

Tags: linux, fedora, virtualbox

When I run df -h I get the following return:

```
[root@localhost ~]# df -h 
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                 983M     0  983M   0% /dev
tmpfs                    997M     0  997M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    997M  1.3M  995M   1% /run
tmpfs                    997M     0  997M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/fedora-root  6.1G  5.8G     0 100% /
tmpfs                    997M   80K  997M   1% /tmp
/dev/sda1                976M  146M  764M  16% /boot
tmpfs                    200M  5.7M  194M   3% /run/user/1000
/dev/sr0                 1.8G  1.8G     0 100% /run/media/joe/Fedora-WS-Live-29-1-2
```

I'm running a Fedora VM on OracleBox. I'm not going to increase the size of /dev/mapper/fedora-root, is there any way to reduce the size of it?

Comment: Delete stuff you don't use/need.

Answer (score 1):

Check if there are any logs which can be removed / compressed using `find / -type f -name *.log`

Also, if its possible try adding more storage to allow breathing space for system.